# Can TCP meltdown happen for TCP over Quic?

Tags: tcp, quic

It is a common knowledge that transferring TCP packet inside a tunnel with TCP connection can create a devastating effect called [TCP meltdown](http://sites.inka.de/%7Ebigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html) and degrade tunnel quality greatly. I somehow wondering if similar effect may happen in we try to transfer TCP data over a Quic connection. Even though Quic is UDP packets, but it need to have something similar to windowing for keeping track of received packets in order to provide a connection-oriented protocol. So I'm not sure if a similar effect will happen or not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUIC indeed uses a similar congestion control as TCP, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9002.html#name-congestion-control. So when tunnelling a TCP connection over a QUIC stream, I would say the same "meltdown" problems can occur (a QUIC stream has the same properties as a TCP connection: reliable ordered stream of byte, so the stream will stall if QUIC packets are lost).

However, a QUIC extensions is being defined for sending datagrams, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-datagram. That might provide a better way for transporting TCP packets, as these datagrams will never be retransmitted at QUIC level. However, it would require TCP packets to fit into a Datagram frame.

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that the proposed extension already had became an RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9221.html. The motivation paragraph even mentions it can be used for IP-tunneling: "Unreliable QUIC datagrams can also be used to implement an IP packet tunnel over QUIC, such as for a Virtual Private Network (VPN)."